# Qgis2threejs error after changes in qgis-ltr-bin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have installed QGIS 2.8.9 in `C:\OSGeo4W` folder and change `qgis-ltr-bin.bat` last line with `start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\surveykshak.exe --configpath "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\qgisini%*`.

I changed this line for making QGIS on stick/USB drive. If I move the OSGEO4W folder to another system; it opens with the same settings.

I start the qgis and it gives me the following errors for first time only:

```
Couldn't load qgis.user.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\user.py", line 47, in 
    import expressions
  File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named expressions


Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
2.0.0-XXXXXXX', exported

Python path:
['C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python', u'C:\\OSGeo4W\\qgisini/python', u'C:\\OSGeo4W\\qgisini/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', u'C:\\OSGeo4W\\qgisini/python']
```

The above error goes off when I open the qgis second time and a folder name qgisini created inside C:\OSGEO4W.

Now I had installed qgis2threejs via Plugin > Manage and install plugin. I am using a dem in UTM projection.

When I run the qgis2threejs it gives me following error:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\qgisini/python/plugins\Qgis2threejs\qgis2threejsdialog.py", line 544, in run
    ret = exportToThreeJS(export_settings, self.iface.legendInterface(), self.objectTypeManager, self.progress)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\qgisini/python/plugins\Qgis2threejs\export.py", line 238, in exportToThreeJS
    writer = ThreejsJSWriter(settings, objectTypeManager, bool(settings.exportMode == ExportSettings.PLAIN_MULTI_RES))
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\qgisini/python/plugins\Qgis2threejs\export.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.demProvider = settings.demProvider()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\qgisini/python/plugins\Qgis2threejs\exportsettings.py", line 142, in demProvider
    return self.demProviderByLayerId(layerId)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\qgisini/python/plugins\Qgis2threejs\exportsettings.py", line 209, in demProviderByLayerId
    return GDALDEMProvider(layer.source(), str(self.crs.toWkt()), source_wkt=str(layer.crs().toWkt()))    # use CRS set to the layer in QGIS
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\qgisini/python/plugins\Qgis2threejs\qgis2threejscore.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.ds.SetProjection(str(source_wkt))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetProjection'


Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
2.0.0-XXXXX, exported

Python path: ['C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python', u'C:\\OSGeo4W\\qgisini/python', u'C:\\OSGeo4W\\qgisini/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', u'C:\\OSGeo4W\\qgisini/python', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis-ltr\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

I already tried it by setting `PYTHONHOME` path and `PATH` variables in environment variables.

Is there any solution to this?
How to remove this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same error two or three times [1].

I could clear away the error by updating `gdal-python` package or
reinstalling an older version of `gdal-python` package at those times.

As a stopgap adding the following line to qgis2threejscore.py line 31
should fix the issue.

```
....
try:
  from osgeo import gdal
except ImportError:
  import gdal

gdal.AllRegister()    # LINE TO ADD

from gdal2threejs import Raster
from geometry import Point
....
```

[1] https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs/issues/63

Comment: This not an answer to the question.